# Unable to connect to Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04, azure-virtual-machine

I created a virtual machine using an Ubuntu image with Discourse preloaded from the Azure gallery. After the automatic setup completed, I can see that the VM is running but I can't connect to it in order to view the machine remotely. I don't see any setting that can resolve this for me. Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a client like Bitvise SSH Client, which is recommended by Microsoft, to perform tasks on your ubuntu VM.